# nested for loop, set variable and if else in a batch script

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, vbscript, cmd

I am trying to make a batch script which will write specific IP addresses in a file.
I have a txt file (created by one python script) having a list of IP addresses (one in each new-line), Now I need to ping each of these IPs using for loop, check if the TTL value is between 100 to 128 (windows hosts) and write the IP addresses to a new file. I've been trying to adjust into setting the variables and for loops but this all becomes too complex to run.
So far I've reached:- 
EDIT: corrected below command

```
for /f %i in (ip.txt) do ping -n 1 %i | find "TTL"
```

This will give me multiple lines Ping output, showing here only for single line (I am using 4.2.2.2 just for example)

```
Reply from 4.2.2.2: bytes=32 time=1 ms ttl=45
```

If I do ping to single IP I can pick the TTL field but not TTL's exact value

```
for /f "tokens=6 delims= " %a in ('ping -n 1 4.2.2.2 ^| find "TTL"') do echo %a
```

It gives me the value `TTL=45` whereas I needed 45 for the comparison.
I read about `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` which is useful, but I am not able to combine these all into a single line and use `set` variables and use `IF-ELSE` loops.
Plz give a little description on how to achieve the IP selection.

***EDITED BY ME AFTER MAKING BATCH SCRIPT SOLUTION:-***
This batch script will ping every IP address given in the **ips.txt** file. Find the TTL value, if TTL value is equal to 128, it'll run a command ***NBTSTAT -A ip-address*** (for finding the GROUP information) and store it in a **nbt_query_op.txt** file.
 This file will be searched for existing results before firing the NBTSTAT command for every IP Address and if the result for a specific IP is not found in the file, NBTSTAT will be fired.
 **Note** that **variables** should be referenced enclosed with **!** characters, **!TTL! , !ip1! , !ERRORLEVEL!**. Further, thanks to Mr. RGuggisberg too for providing pointers.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f %%i in (ips.txt) do (
for /f "tokens=6 delims= " %%a in ('ping -n 1 %%i ^| find "TTL"') do (
    for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%b in ('echo.%%a') do set ttl=%%b
    echo %%i has TTL:- !ttl!
    if !TTL! == 128      (set ip1=%%i
                 echo        SELECTED IP- !ip1! TTL- !TTL!
                 findstr /c:!ip1! nbt_query_op.txt
                 if not !ERRORLEVEL! ==0 echo !ip1!>>nbt_query_op.txt && nbtstat -A !ip1! | find "GROUP">>nbt_query_op.txt
                     )
                                          )
)
```

Thanks,
 kriss

Comment: Read the tag descriptions before you apply them! [tag:ms-dos] is an OS from the 1980s, I'm sure you're not working with that, but you're using [tag:windows]... Regard that you need to use `%%i` rather than `%i` in a batch script, `%i` only works in command prompt (`cmd`) directly.

Comment: aschipfl: Thanks. I am going to use %% with variables in batch file, but I'll have to use a one line command with system() function in other script. So will have to use %i for straight DOS execution. It is going to be used as DOS command.<br> Maybe someone can join the dots together with IF-ELSE and SET stuff, as I am not able to use all of it together.

Comment: Once again: it's not **DOS**, it's command prompt, or `cmd`! if you are looking for a `cmd` command line as well, you should edit your question and add the [tag:cmd] tag...

Comment: If you want we can do it in vbscript !

Comment: To clarify the history and terms, MS-DOS uses the COMMAND.COM shell to execute batch files, and its console support is implemented in the kernel (IO.SYS). Windows NT uses the cmd.exe shell to execute batch files, and its console support is split between kernel mode (condrv.sys), the Windows subsystem (conhost.exe, csrss.exe), and the client DLLs kernel32.dll and ntdll.dll. The cmd shell is not the console, just as bash on a Linux system is not a terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In vbscript you can do something like this :

```
strHost = "4.2.2.2"
if Ping(strHost) = True then
    Wscript.Echo "Host " & strHost & " contacted"
Else
    Wscript.Echo "Host " & strHost & " could not be contacted"
end if
'***************************************************************************************
Function Ping(strHost)
    dim objPing, objRetStatus
    set objPing = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}").ExecQuery _
      ("select * from Win32_PingStatus where address = '" & strHost & "'")
    for each objRetStatus in objPing
        if IsNull(objRetStatus.StatusCode) or objRetStatus.StatusCode <> 0 then
            Ping = False
            WScript.Echo "Status code is " & objRetStatus.StatusCode
        else
            Ping = True
            Msg = Msg & " Pingging " & strHost & vbCrlf & vbCrlf 
            Msg = Msg & "Bytes = " & objRetStatus.BufferSize & vbCrlf 
            Msg = Msg & "Time (ms) = " & objRetStatus.ResponseTime & vbCrlf 
            Msg = Msg & "TTL (s) = "  & objRetStatus.ResponseTimeToLive 
        end if
    next
    Wscript.echo Msg
End Function 
'***************************************************************************************
```

**EDIT : On 30/06/2016 @ 19:11**

I tested with this file : file.txt

> ```
> 4.2.2.2
> www.google.com
> www.google.fr
> www.facebook.com
> www.stackoverflow.com
> www.yahoo.com
> www.yahoo.fr
> www.developpez.net
> ```

this batch file :

```
@echo off
Title Get TTL from IP adress
set vbsfile=%Tmp%\%~n0.vbs
set IP_File=E:\vb-ping\ip.txt
set LogFile=Log.txt
If Exist %LogFile% Del %LogFile%
For /f %%a in ('Type %IP_File%') Do ( 
    echo TTL for "%%a" is : & Call:VBS "%%a"
    ( echo TTL for "%%a" is : & Call:VBS "%%a" )>> %LogFile%
)
echo.
color 0A
echo Hit any key to open the LogFile "%LogFile%"
pause>nul
Start "" %LogFile%
Exit /b

:VBS 
(
    echo wscript.echo TTL(WScript.Arguments(0^)^)
    echo '**********************************************************************************************************
    echo Function TTL(strHost^)
    echo     dim objPing, objRetStatus
    echo     set objPing = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}"^).ExecQuery _
    echo       ("select * from Win32_PingStatus where address = '" ^& strHost ^& "'"^)
    echo     for each objRetStatus in objPing
    echo         if IsNull(objRetStatus.StatusCode^) or objRetStatus.StatusCode ^<^> 0 then
    echo            Ping = False
    echo           WScript.Echo "Status code is " ^& objRetStatus.StatusCode
    echo        else
    echo            Ping = True
    echo            TTL = objRetStatus.ResponseTimeToLive 
    echo        end if
    echo     next
    echo End Function 
    echo '**********************************************************************************************************
)> "%vbsfile%"
Cscript /Nologo "%vbsfile%" "%~1"
Exit /b
```

And i got as output result like that :

> ```
> TTL for "4.2.2.2" is : 
> 53
> TTL for "www.google.com" is : 
> 51
> TTL for "www.google.fr" is : 
> 51
> TTL for "www.facebook.com" is : 
> 81
> TTL for "www.stackoverflow.com" is : 
> 53
> TTL for "www.yahoo.com" is : 
> 48
> TTL for "www.yahoo.fr" is : 
> 48
> TTL for "www.developpez.net" is : 
> 48
> ```

Comment: Thanks Hackoo, It worked superb. I guess I'll have to start learning VB Scripting too now. Tell me, is it easier compared to Batch scripting? And any good reference to start with it? In fact, In my script, I did the initial job by using **NMAP** with **python** and **REGEX** to get IPs which are live & having a DNS entry in my network. That part was quite easy. Now I just needed to get their TTL values using **DOS** command. To my surprise I couldn't store the Python's results to a variable, so tried using nested DOS loops.

Comment: I gave **upvote** to both the answers, but I don't see them upvoted. Don't understand why !!!

Comment: @user2593869 Check and test my last edit and tell me the results ;)

Comment: Thanks for the script. I got errors about **The system cannot find the file specified** in CMD and **Windows cannot find Log.txt** if ran from explorer. I am confused with the file-location of files mentioned at line numbers 2, 3 & 4 of your batch file  Should that not be a full file path? Sorry, I am noob with VBscripts currently.

Comment: @user2593869 What is the name of the file that contains the ip adresses ? and where is located ?

Comment: The IP address file is ip.txt and it is in E:\vb-ping\

Comment: @user2593869 I edit my script and i change to yours, just give a try and tell me !

Comment: @user2593869 I edit my last script and i change to yours, just give a try and tell me !

Comment: superb. Worked flawlessly. One last request plz. Can I have the TTL value in the same line having IP address? It'll be very handy to parse the Log file. Anyways if it cumbersome, then ignore it, I'll manage with **grep -B** ;) . Thank you. DOS/VbScript is always preferred because of native support on windows box. Thanks once again. BTW the handle Hackoo is cool one, reminds me of PWK LABs ;)

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you are asking. Modify as needed when you migrate to your first example.

```
for /f "tokens=6 delims= " %a in ('ping -n 1 4.2.2.2 ^| find "TTL"') do for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %b in ('echo.%a') do echo %b
```

BTW, the first FOR loop in your post is incomplete. I think you meant

```
for /f %i in (ip.txt) do ping -n 1 %i | find "TTL"
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Guggisberg. It worked and I can get the value of TTL correctly. I am working on joining all the for Loops and IF conditions. Will post further if I need some more help. Thanks :)

Comment: I prepared the TTL-time filtering command for later use and now I am now trying to combine the two ***for loops*** as follows:-    ***for /f %a in (ip.txt) do ping -n 1 %a | find "TTL" do for /f "tokens=6 delims= " %b in ('echo.%a') do echo %b***  .  
But gives me error:- ***FIND: Invalid switch***   .  
Further I have to insert ***SET*** , ***IF*** & ***echo*** statement too after solving it. Anybody on this error?

Comment: Take a look at my answer. You removed the first "tokens=..." and altered the 2nd one. You can append this to your command & set "YourVarName=%b"

Comment: Mr. Guggisberg. Your solution was great and had shown me the result by pinging one IP (whereas I've to ping multiple IPs in loop). So I was trying to fit your solution in reading the IP-addresses from file, then ping them one by one and then echo the TTL's mixed value (I'll filter out the exact TTL numeric value later). So what I am trying to get:- **get the ping result line** by running ***for /f %a in (ip.txt) do ping -n 1 %a | find "TTL"*** , then pass it to ***do for /f "tokens=6 delims= " %b in ('echo.%a') do echo %b*** to get ***TTL=45*** . So, ping IPs, pass the result to tokens & echo.

Comment: This is getting a bit hard to follow for those of us that can not see what you see. Perhaps you should post your ip.txt file (or at least a few lines of it) and what you expect to get as an end result (or at least a few results that correspond to the few lines of ip.txt.

Comment: ip.txt file is having ip-addresses written line by line. I don't know how to separate them here. But one line has only one IP, then another IP in second line and so on...

Comment: Thanks for following up. Further after pinging them I need to get the IP addresses in result who match a specific range of TTL values, for example say- 128 or 127 or 126. Since I am searching for live windows hosts and TTL values may keep decrementing as they may be after 1 or 2 hops. 192.168.1.1 may have a TTL value of 127, 192.168.2.1 may have TTL value of 126. So I need to ping them and if the TTL value falls in the range of 120 to 128, then echo those IP addresses or write them to a file.

Answer (score 1):

So, my answer seems to turn to a somewhat different one than I was seeking. It is in python 2.x I just finished writing. Although it is not very sophisticated and stealth in terms of execution (pops up lots of CMD windows and writes to files and then reads to form the result). But still got the job done. I guess I'll have to do more research on DOS commands and start learning VB Scripting ;). lol.
Thank you @RGuggisberg and @Hackoo for the support

```
import os
import re
cwd = os.getcwd()
ip_file = cwd+"\\ip.txt"     ## IPs written in this file, one in each line, or the filename can be taken through command-line args (more portable)
ip = []
win_hosts = []
for line in open(ip_file).readlines():
    ip.append(line.rstrip())
del_cmd = "del "+cwd+"\\response.txt"    ## Delete response.txt file
os.system(del_cmd)                       ## as PING output keeps appending to it
for i in ip:
    cmd = "ping -n 1 "+str(i)+' | find "TTL" >> response.txt'    ## write PING response to response.txt
    os.system(cmd)
response_file = cwd+"\\response.txt"
for line in open(response_file).readlines():
    regs = r'Reply from\s(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}).*TTL=(\d{1,3})'   ## Regular Expression to catch IP and TTL-value
    obj = re.search(regs,line.rstrip('\n'))  ## also right-strip any possible new-lines, it'll probably be '\r\n' on Linux host
    if obj:
        ip = obj.group(1)
        ttl = obj.group(2)
        print ip," has TTL= ",ttl
        ttl = int(ttl)
        if (127<ttl<129):                ## change this to (54<ttl<65) to get Linux hosts
            win_hosts.append(ip)         ## Add the windows hosts to win_hosts list
print "\n[+][+] Windows Hosts = ",str(win_hosts)
```

My ip.txt file has:-

```
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.4
192.168.1.5
```

The result is:-

```
>>> 
192.168.1.1  has TTL=  30
192.168.1.2  has TTL=  64
192.168.1.4  has TTL=  64
192.168.1.5  has TTL=  128

[+][+] Windows Hosts =  ['192.168.1.5']
```

I don't exactly remember but couldn't get support of **commands module** (not supported on Windows) and **subprocess module** (*Though they work flawlessly on Linux box*). If someone has any idea on how to store their result to any list/dictionary/variable, plz update. I didn't like using output re-directions in CMD.

Answer (score 1):

Give a try for this batch file to get the `TTL` value in the same line having IP address

```
@echo off
Title Get TTL from IP adress
set vbsfile=%Tmp%\%~n0.vbs
set IP_File=E:\vb-ping\ip.txt
set LogFile=Log.txt
If Exist %LogFile% Del %LogFile%
For /f %%a in ('Type %IP_File%') Do ( 
     Call:VBS "%%a" & echo  %%a
    ( Call:VBS "%%a" & echo  %%a)>> %LogFile%
)
echo.
color 0A
echo Hit any key to open the LogFile "%LogFile%"
pause>nul
Start "" %LogFile%
Exit /b

:VBS 
(
    echo WScript.StdOut.Write TTL(WScript.Arguments(0^)^)
    echo '**********************************************************************************************************
    echo Function TTL(strHost^)
    echo     dim objPing, objRetStatus
    echo     set objPing = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}"^).ExecQuery _
    echo       ("select * from Win32_PingStatus where address = '" ^& strHost ^& "'"^)
    echo     for each objRetStatus in objPing
    echo         if IsNull(objRetStatus.StatusCode^) or objRetStatus.StatusCode ^<^> 0 then
    echo            Ping = False
    echo           WScript.Echo "Status code is " ^& objRetStatus.StatusCode
    echo        else
    echo            Ping = True
    echo            TTL = objRetStatus.ResponseTimeToLive 
    echo        end if
    echo     next
    echo End Function 
    echo '**********************************************************************************************************
)> "%vbsfile%"
Cscript /Nologo "%vbsfile%" "%~1"
Exit /b
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I created the full scanning script for all the Windows clients which are not a part of my Org's Domain. It's been enough long time, but I thought to post it here.
This script relies on initial client's scan with ping-sweep of **nmap**. Since creating script using **multiprocessing** module didn't work on windows box, so the best shot was *nmap*. NMAP does a ping-sweep of full subnet of 255 hosts within few seconds and returns the FQDN (Fully qualified domain names) of the clients found alive in the network.
 **NOTE:** you should hve the DNS server defined in your scanner PC.
Next thing the script does is, /ites the nmap scan's output to a file **nmap_op.txt**. Then scripts reads the output from this file and uses regular-expression to take out IP and FQDN. If any IP isn't having FQDN, it is pinged once and output is written to a file **response.txt**. This file is read and IPs having TTL value between 100-129 are taken out.
**add_to_db** function is responsible for returning a list of IP which actually do not belong to Domain. This function crosschecks the IPs with 3  lists and removes the IP from final list which was in the database file but later was joined to Domain and also keeps adding new non-domain IPs to DB as and when they come online.
Save this python file in a directory where the script could be able to write files. You should look for two files **non-domain-ips.txt** (all non domain IPs) and **[subnet_value]-result.txt** for the final results.
**Usage**- run this file in command prompt as follows:-
***python scanner.py 192.168.1.0/24 192.168.2.0/24***

You can add any number of networks to scan. Plz do not change the pattern of network arg. You must use **"/"**  only to define the mask value of network (do not use * in place of /). There is no exception handling on the arguments being passed. Rest of the output will be understood when you run the script.
Further I am thinking to add one or two more functions to define some IPs as exception as per the Vendor's bits of their MAC-Address. For example- some thin-client type devices (as they are going to run in standalone mode only) which give the TTL value of windows range.
The script was made in quite a hurry without any use of classes (moreover I'm not very fond of them), so it's in it's ugliest form ;)

```
import os
import time
import re
import sys
import pickle
import commands
import subprocess

def add_to_db(nondomain_ips, pickled_ips, domainIPs):
    print "NON domain IPs= ", str(nondomain_ips)
    #raw_input("....")
    print "PICKLED IPs= ",str(pickled_ips)
    #raw_input("....")
    print "Length of PICKLED IPs= ",len(pickled_ips)
    print "domain IPs:- ",str(domainIPs)
    #raw_input("....")
    if (len(pickled_ips) == 0):
        pickled_ips= nondomain_ips
        return pickled_ips
    for new_ip in nondomain_ips:
        print "comparing- ",str(new_ip)
        if new_ip not in pickled_ips:
            print "APPENDING ",str(new_ip),"  to PICKLED IPs"
            pickled_ips.append(new_ip)           
        else:   pass
    for pickled_ip in pickled_ips:
        #print "CHECKING - ",pickled_ip," in domain and in DB file or not"
        if pickled_ip in domainIPs:
            print pickled_ip," JOINED domain, removing from DB file"
            pickled_ips.remove(pickled_ip)
    #print "PICKLED IPs:- ",str(pickled_ips)
    #raw_input("...")
    return pickled_ips
def main():
    if (len(sys.argv)<2):
        print "Wrong args, Give the subnet to scan, Example- \n\npython script.py 192.168.1.0/24 192.168.2.0/24 [more subnets...]\n\nExiting...\n"
        exit(3)
    print "TOTAL SUBNETS TO SCAN:- ",len(sys.argv)
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    print "Current Directory= ",cwd
    outfile = cwd+"\\nmap_op.txt"
    for i in range(1,len(sys.argv)):
    time_now = time.ctime()
        net = sys.argv[i]
        #print i
        #cmd = "nmap -sn " + str(sys.argv[i]) + " -oG "+str(outfile)
        cmd = "nmap -sn " + str(net) + " -oG "+str(outfile)
        print cmd
        try:
            os.remove(outfile)
        except Exception, e:
            print "Error deleting file",str(e)
        #raw_input("SENDING -sn SCAN....\n")
        print "SENDING -sn SCAN....\n"
        os.system(cmd)

        #print "Argv[i]= ",sys.argv[i].split('/')[0]
        print "Argv[i]= ",net.split('/')[0]
        result_file = str(cwd)+"\\"+net.split('/')[0]+"-result.txt"
        print "result file= ",result_file
        #raw_input(" ... ")
        if os.path.exists(outfile):
            print outfile," - oG file created\n\n-------------------------------------\n"
        fp = open(outfile)
        hostlist=[]
        domainIPs = []
        nondomain = []
        ping_file = cwd+"\\response.txt"
        try:
            os.remove(ping_file)
        except Exception, e:
            e=e
        for line in fp.readlines():
            #print line
            #reg = r'Host:(.*\)).*Status.*Up'
            reg = r'Host:\s(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\s(\(.*\)).*Status.*Up'
            res = re.match(reg,line)
            if res:
                #print "\t\t",res.group()
                ip = res.group(1)
                if ('()' in res.group(2)):
                    name = 0
                    nondomain.append([ip,name])
                    ping_cmd = 'ping -n 1 '+str(ip)+'| find "TTL" >>'+cwd+"\\response.txt"
                    os.system(ping_cmd)
                else:
                    name = res.group(2)
                    domainIPs.append(ip)
                hostlist.append([ip,name])
            else:   pass #print "No object"
        fp.close()      ## CLOSE THE NMAP OUTPUT FILE-HANDLE
        print "[+][+] All HOSTS:- ",str(hostlist),"\n"
        #print "domain IPs:- ",str(domainIPs)
        print "TOTAL unresolved IPs:- ",nondomain,"\n"
        nondomain_ip = []
        #print "\n\nIP and TTL from RegExp\n"
        regs = r'Reply from\s(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}).*TTL=(\d{1,3})'
        for line in open(ping_file).readlines():
            #print line
            obj = re.search(regs,line)
            if obj:
                ip = obj.group(1)
                ttl = obj.group(2)
                print str(ip)+" --- " + str(ttl)
                if (100<int(ttl)<129):
                    nondomain_ip.append(ip)
        #print "non domain IPs = ",str(nondomain_ip)
        fp_result = open(result_file,'a')
        fp_result.write("\n\n"+time_now+"\n")
        fp_result.write(str(nondomain_ip))
        fp_result.close()

        db_file = cwd+"\\dbfile"
        if not os.path.exists(db_file):
            fpdb = open(db_file,'w')
            fpdb.close()
            if os.path.exists(db_file):
                print "DB_FILE created"
        with open(db_file,'rb') as fpdb:
            try:
                pickled_ips = pickle.load(fpdb)
            except Exception, error:
                print "Error in loading pickeled list"
                pickled_ips = []
                print "Formed new pickled list= ",str(pickled_ips)
        fpdb.close()
        new_list = add_to_db(nondomain_ip, pickled_ips, domainIPs)
        #print "\nNEW IP-ADDRESSES ESTABLISHED AFTER COMPARING ALL LISTS:- \n",str(new_list)
        with open(db_file, 'wb') as fpdb:
            pickle.dump(new_list, fpdb)
        fpdb.close()
        with open(db_file, 'rb') as fpdb:
            ips = pickle.load(fpdb)
            print "\n\n\t\tTHE NON-domain IPs:- \n",str(ips)
            with open("non-domain-ips.txt",'wb') as handle:
                for ip in ips:
                    handle.write(ip)
                    handle.write("\r\n")
            handle.close()
        print "SLEEPING FOR 10 SECONDS..."
        time.sleep(10)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        main()
        print "\n\n\n\t\tSCAN COMPLETED...sleep for 5 minutes before running another loop of scan...\n\n\n"
        time.sleep(300)
```